# Accessing structure sub-type fields in Scheme and Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

In Racket this gives me an error:

```
(struct point-in-plane  (pos_x pos_y))  
(struct pixel point-in-plane (color))  

(define a-pixel (pixel 1 2 "blue"))  
(pixel-color a-pixel)  
(pixel-pos_x a-pixel) 
(pixel-pos_y a-pixel)
```

For it to work I need to replace the last two lines with:

```
(point-in-plane-pos_x a-pixel) 
(point-in-plane-pos_y a-pixel)
```

Similarly in R6RS

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs))
(define-record-type point (fields x y))
(define-record-type cpoint (parent point) (fields color))
(define blue-point  (make-cpoint 1 2 "blue"))
(write (cpoint-x blue-point))
```

Gives a similar error.

What is the reason Scheme (and Racket) don't allow you to access the fields of a subtype that were defined in the parent by:
subtypeID-fieldID instead of by parenttypeID-fieldID

I.e. in my case allowing me to use pixel-pos_x and pixel-pos_y .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One reason is that `struct` allows you to define sub-structs with identically named fields. For example:

```
(struct base (x y))
(struct sub base (x y))

(define rec (sub 1 2 3 4))
(base-x rec) ; => 1
(sub-x rec)  ; => 3
```

This is because structs don't really know about field names. From the [Racket documentation](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/reference/structures.html): "A structure type’s fields are essentially unnamed, though names are supported for error-reporting purposes." You would have to disallow this behavior in order to get extra accessors for sub-structs.

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._struct%29%29) of the *struct* form says that it provides accessors and setters for the given fields, but doesn't say that it will automatically re-expose the existing accessors and setters of the parent type with the extra names you're expecting.

When I'm dealing with structs and pulling out the components by name, I often use the [racket/match](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) library, especially with the [struct*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/match..rkt%29._struct*%29%29) pattern matcher.  Usually, I have to deal with multiple components of a struct, and the matcher makes it easy to do so.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  If you have an example on hand you could send me (to harryspier@hotmail.com) it would help me immensely.